# itertools returning which list it found a match from

Tags: python, python-itertools

I'm new so bear with me.. I could create two separate for loops but I like this method since I'll probably iterate through multiple lists and this is less code. Is it possible in itertools? As I understand it, it creates one list out of the two so I might be out of luck.

```
import itertools

a = [0, 1, 2]
b = [3, 4, 5]


def finditem(n):
    for i in itertools.chain(a, b):
        if i == n:
            print(n)  #  here i want (n) and (a or b)


n = 3
finditem(n)
```

Comment: It is better use zip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is:

- given a list of lists and an item to find if it exists in that list
- tell me what list that item was found in.

You should probably create a dictionary with your keys being what that list is called and the values for the things in that collection

```py
my_lists = {'a': [0, 1, 2], 'b': [3, 4, 5]}

def find_item(my_lists, item_to_find):
    for key in my_lists:
        if item_to_find in my_lists[key]:
            print(key)
n=3
find_item(my_lists, n)
```

Comment: Your description is on point. This outputs the actual list, but how do return the variable in which the list is contained?

Comment: generally you wouldn't want to do this. In almost all cases you'd want to define a ```dict``` that maps your list names to the list items. for example ```my_lists = {'a': [0, 1, 2], 'b': ['3, 4, 5]}```. why **must** you use the variable name?

Comment: For sorting purposes. I'll try to demonstrate:

my_lists = {'fruits': [0, 1, 2], 'vegetables': ['3, 4, 5]}

if fruits
    do this
if vegetables
    do that

Comment: That's not a variable, that's a dictionary key.

Comment: Yes, that realization solved it for me! I can return key, value in a loop through that.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much need for `itertools` here, but you should store your data in a dictionary if you want to be able to give them labels that you can refer to in the program. To list all of the list names containing `n`:

```
lists = {'fruits': [0, 1, 2], 'vegetables': [3, 4, 5]}
def find_item(n, lists):
    for name, list_ in lists.items():
        if n in list_:
            print(name)
```

or similarly:

```
print([name for name, list_ in lists.items() if n in list_])
```

or to print only the first list found that contains `n`:

```
print(next(name for name, list_ in lists.items() if n in list_))
```

If you need this for an `if` condition, and the number of lists is not very large, then probably don't use a loop in the first place, but a simple condition like this:

```
fruits = [0, 1, 2]
vegetables = [3, 4, 5]
if n in fruits:
    # do this
elif n in vegetables:
    # do that
```

Comment: this helps a lot! however, I want to print the variable in which the list is contained. So if n is in list a, I need the loop to return a.

Comment: Use a dictionary, as suggested in the comments to the other answer. See edits.